# Raw request made by boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to intercept the request which is happening under the hood of the following snippet of code:

```
s3 = boto3.client(
        's3', 
        aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
        )

presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
        Bucket = S3_BUCKET,
        Key = file_name,
        Fields = {"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
        Conditions = [
            {"acl": "public-read"},
            {"Content-Type": file_type}
            ],
        ExpiresIn = 3600
        )
```

I didn't find any docs from amazon explaining how to make those requests by hand. I need to implement the behavior above in Elixir, which doesn't have an AWS SDK available.

How can I intercept the request to create it manually elsewhere?

Answer (score 6):

Enable debug logs and it'll print them out

```
import boto3
boto3.set_stream_logger(name='botocore')
```

Answer (score 1):

Intercept how exactly? To view the final request that is generated? You could do that with something like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/). I'm not sure intercepting the requests is the best way to reverse engineer Boto3 though. I would have a look at [the Boto3 source code](https://github.com/boto/boto3), and familiarize yourself with [the AWS REST API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html) which is the API that the various AWS SDKs are calling behind the scenes. You'll need to implement [Signature Version 4](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) signing of requests in the language you are working in.

It looks like [there's already an Elixir library](https://github.com/handnot2/sigaws) for AWS Signature V4. And furthermore it looks like someone has already released an [Elixir AWS SDK](https://github.com/jkakar/aws-elixir) that someone generated from the same JSON descriptions that are used to build the AWS SDK for Go.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, generation of a pre-signed URL does not involve an API call to AWS. You can create your own pre-signed URLs using a few lines of code.

See:[Python Code Search Engine - http://www.pythonexample.com/code/generate-pre-signed-url/](http://www.pythonexample.com/code/generate-pre-signed-url/)

Here is a sample from that page:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
Generates a pre-signed S3 URL using a valid key pair that lasts for 20 years.

Reference: http://forrst.com/posts/Python_method_for_creating_authenticated_s3_URLs-uUM
"""


import base64, hmac, os, sha, sys, time, urllib


if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print 'USAGE: python s3_presign.py "</bucket-name/path/to/resource"> <seconds-alive>'
    exit(1)


# Declarations:
TWENTY_YEARS_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 20
aws_access_key_id = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
aws_secret_access_key = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
resource = sys.argv[1]
seconds_alive = TWENTY_YEARS_IN_SECONDS if len(sys.argv) < 3 else int(sys.argv[2])


# Computations:
expires = int(time.time()) + seconds_alive
resource = urllib.quote(resource)
raw_value = "GET\n\n\n{0}\n{1}".format(expires, resource)
signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(aws_secret_access_key, raw_value, sha).digest())


# Result:
print "https://s3.amazonaws.com{0}?AWSAccessKeyId={1}&Expires={2}&Signature={3}".format(
    resource, urllib.quote(aws_access_key_id), expires, urllib.quote(signature))
```